# Wordpress Post Text Excerpt in Sidebar?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am curious if there is a way to output an excerpt of the post txt into a sidebar, but only the sidebar for that post.

What I have tried is using the get_content loop in the single.php into a custom sibar that I have created inside another DIV, but it displays the post txt, Comments and images in the sidebar.

```
 <div id="Sidebar">
   <?php the_content(); ?>
 </div>
```

Question: Is there anyway to display Post text in the sidebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <?php 
       the_content();

       //display only on post page 
       if(is_single()){
          the_excerpt();           
       }
</div>
```

Hope that works!